# Writing an SQL Query to simplify the given example

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a problem that requires multiple queries to be executed in order to find a result. How can I get this done in one query, as I need to improve performance?

Basically, I need to pick items from Table A that share common rows in Table B with a given User's items.

> Select people from Usertable

**If**

> 1) They have any fruits that the User already has

Example:

> Roger has apples and oranges. Kenneth has Mangoes and Apples. Julie has Mangoes .

**Question**: Pick the people who share common fruits with Roger

The Query picks Kenneth because he shares an item (apples) with Roger.

Obviously I can get this done using 3 queries and by following the steps given below:

1) Select the people

2) Run a foreach of each user's items

3) If the user contains Roger's fruits, pick them

**How can I do this in one query?**

Comment: SO is not meant to do your homework ;-) Please show your effort: What have you tried so far? Provide sample data and expected output...

Comment: @Shnugo Well I have tried it. Using 3 long queries, which I have mentioned in the question :) I wanted it all in 1 query

Comment: This is a quite simple challenge. Your "long queries" cannot be that long, that they wouldn't fit into this page ;-) Everybody is keen to help you, but you should at least prepare sample data and expected output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without exact table structure can't give proper answer. but you can use `'IN'` clause

```
select * from Usertable a join userfruit b on .....
where b. fruit in ( select fruit from userfruit where username='Roger')
```

Pls Check this demo [SQLFiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ad2e/5/0)

Comment: The multi-part identifier "Usertable.Name" could not be bound. This is at "...JOIN userfruit b ON Usertable.Name.."

Comment: @Earthling check demo

Comment: Btw How can I get column values from Table b as well as Table a in "SELECT a.* FROM". What change should I make to get values from Table b as well? b.* and a.*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.username 
FROM Usertable a 
JOIN userfruit b 
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
WHERE 
    a.fruit IN (
        SELECT b.fruit 
        FROM userfruit
        WHERE username='Roger'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a select like below and while iterating the results, add to a structure `Map<UserName, List<Fruits>>`.

```
select usertable.name, userfruits.fruitname from usertable join userfruits on (usertable.name = userfruits.username) order by usertable.name;
```

This will give you result of following kind:

```
Name             |FruitName
----------------------------
Julie            |Mangoes
Kenneth          |Apple
Kenneth          |Mangoes
Roger            |Apple
Roger            |Orange
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpPerson (
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(32)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpFruit (
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(32)
)

CREATE TABLE #tmpPersonFruit (
    PersonId INT,
    FruitId INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpPerson (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Roger')
INSERT INTO #tmpPerson (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Kenneth')
INSERT INTO #tmpPerson (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Julie')

INSERT INTO #tmpFruit (Id, Name) VALUES (1, 'Apples')
INSERT INTO #tmpFruit (Id, Name) VALUES (2, 'Oranges')
INSERT INTO #tmpFruit (Id, Name) VALUES (3, 'Mangoes')

INSERT INTO #tmpPersonFruit (PersonId, FruitId) VALUES(1, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpPersonFruit (PersonId, FruitId) VALUES(1, 2)
INSERT INTO #tmpPersonFruit (PersonId, FruitId) VALUES(2, 1)
INSERT INTO #tmpPersonFruit (PersonId, FruitId) VALUES(2, 3)
INSERT INTO #tmpPersonFruit (PersonId, FruitId) VALUES(3, 3)

GO

DECLARE @Person NVARCHAR(64)
SET @Person = 'Roger'

SELECT          Person.Name AS PersonName,
                Fruit.Name AS FruitName

FROM            #tmpPerson AS Person

INNER JOIN      #tmpPersonFruit AS PersonFruit
    ON          Person.Id = PersonFruit.PersonId

INNER JOIN( SELECT          F.*
                FROM (          SELECT          *
                                FROM            #tmpPerson
                                WHERE           Name = @Person) AS P
                INNER JOIN      #tmpPersonFruit AS PF
                    ON          P.Id = PF.PersonId

                INNER JOIN      #tmpFruit AS F
                    ON          PF.FruitId = F.Id) AS Fruit
    ON          PersonFruit.FruitId = Fruit.Id

GO

DROP TABLE #tmpPerson
DROP TABLE #tmpFruit
DROP TABLE #tmpPersonFruit
```

---

Let me know if you need the full explanation of why this works.